# how to store firebase snap.val() in a varible to use else where?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, firebase

how would one go and store data from the firebase database using javascript. I want to use the once method so its not constantly looking up for any changes.
For example like this:

```
database.child('readOnly/something').once('value').then((snap) => {
        const groupObj = [
            snap.val()
        ]
    });
    app.get('/something',(req,res)=>{
            res.render('something',{
                "groupList": groupObj
            });
        });
            // Individual Life Groups
            app.get('/something/:name',(req,res)=>{
                const group = req.path.split("/").pop();
                console.log(groupObj.length)
                for (i = 0; i < groupObj.length; i+=1) { 
                    if(groupObj[i].url   == group){
                        var desiredGroup = groupObj[i];
                        console.log(desiredGroup);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                res.render('group', desiredGroup);
                // To-Do: Add Data and Bindings
            });
```

I am using the up to date versions of expressjs, firebase, nodejs, and npm.

Comment: the same value for the life of the application? or do you expect it to change. Shared among all requests/users?

Comment: The value is the same until '/something' is called again

Comment: Then yeah you could essentially store that value in a location available to all calls of the routes that need it and just reuse it.

Comment: Thank you that ended up working for me

Answer (score 0):

You could place the `groupObj` variable in a "global" area so all callbacks can use it.

```
const groupObj = [];

database.child('readOnly/something').once('value').then((snap) => {
  groupObj.push(snap.val());
});

app.get('/something',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('something',{
        "groupList": groupObj
    });
});

// Individual Life Groups
app.get('/something/:name',(req,res)=>{
    const group = req.path.split("/").pop();
    console.log(groupObj.length)
    for (i = 0; i < groupObj.length; i+=1) { 
        if(groupObj[i].url   == group){
            var desiredGroup = groupObj[i];
            console.log(desiredGroup);
            break;
        }
    }
    res.render('group', desiredGroup);
    // To-Do: Add Data and Bindings
});
```

Comment: When I do that all I'm getting is an empty array